# Why does calling a JS function from onsubmit clear my form and console?

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

I am trying to call a JS function via the onsubmit event on a form.  When I do this, my form input gets cleared (as does my JS console where I was trying to debug this issue).  The JS from my functions appears to run, but I'm not sure why the form and console are cleared. Can someone explain?

If I call the same JS function via the onclick event on a button, the form and console are not cleared.  Is there something special about calling this JS function based on the onsubmit event that causes the behavior I'm seeing?

Here is an HTML file that reproduces this issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

   <body>   
    <script>
      function doThis(){
        console.log("Hello World");
      }
      function doThat(){
        console.log("Goodbye World");
      }
    </script>

    <form onsubmit="doThis()">
        <label>Address: </label><input type="text" name="address"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    <button onclick="doThat()">Submit Button</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because your form _is_ actually submitted, so the page gets reloaded – since you did not cancel the original behavior of the event. And it doesn’t happen with your `button`, because a) that is not even part of your form, and b) even if it was, a `button` does not submit a form unless it has `type="submit"` attribute set …

Comment: @CBroe `type="submit"` is the default of a `<button>`. It just doesn't have a form to submit with "a)."

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: You’re correct, I remembered that wrongly, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is getting submitted, which reloads the page and displays a new clean form and console.

To cancel submission add `return false;` to the `onsubmit` OR add a JavaScript breakpoint inside `doThis()`.

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` should return some value `true` if form may proceed to be submited and `false` to prevent it. By default it is `true` so your form is submited and refreshing the page.

Comment: Thanks!  This helped.  Turns out that if I use: onsubmit="return tryThis()", and then return false from tryThis(), the form is not submitted and the page does not reload.

Answer (score -2):

I gone through same problem when i developed form for submitting user data at server from iframe, every time user filled up form data and click on submit button that form reset to original state but i do not want to reset form automatically. I investigated  and found that "submit" button default behavior is to submit form data and reset form to original state. After that i have used simple button and invoked function on click of button for posting data.